# DownValues when using Set and SetDelayed

Tags: functions, core-language

It is known from several questions asked in SE that one of the basic differences between `Set` and `SetDelayed` is that the former evaluates the right hand side at the time of assignment whereas the other is not.

When I looked at the `DownValues` in both cases I found that both definitions result into same `DownValues` structures.

For example:

```
t = x + y
f[x_, y_] := 2 x t
g[x_, y_] = 2 x t
```

Now:

```
DownValues/@{f,g}

    (*{{HoldPattern[f[x_, y_]] :> 2 x t}, {HoldPattern[g[x_, y_]] :> 2 x (x + y)}}*)
```

As you can see here that both `Set` and `SetDelayed` transformed into same `DownValues` structures (`HoldPattern[function pattern] :> right hand side`)

My questions are:

1-Is it correct that internally both will be treated equally based on `DownValues` structure.

2- If I want to define function using `SetDelayed` I can do it like this:

```
DownValues[h]={HoldPattern[h[x_, y_]] :> 2 x t};
```

[image]

Now how to do same thing with `Set`

Thanks

Comment: @Guess who it is, nice catch. It is embarrassing to make mistake with function name that you continually use. -:)

Comment: You can actually just `DownValues[h]={HoldPattern[h[x_, y_]] -> 2 x t};` to emulate `Set`.  When you look at `DownValues`, it will always be shown as `:>` and never as `->`.  But when you set it you can use `->`.  When storing it, `:>` is necessary because the downvalue should not change just because `t` was assigned a different value *after* the downvalue was set.  Mathematica does keep track of whether a (downvalue) definition was made with `=` or `:=`, and does print it differently with `Information` or `Defitnition`.   I think I once asked about where this information is stored, but ...

Comment: ... I forgot the answer and cannot find the questin anymore.

Comment: @Szabolcs that explain things better. When you say MMA trucks whether a `DownValues` definition was mad with `=` or `:=`, what makes difference then if at the end the substitution will look at `DownValues` only? In another words why does MMA keep truck the definitions?

Comment: Strongly related SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5919284/590388

Answer (score 1):

To do same thing with `Set`

```
DownValues[h] = {First[Hold[HoldPattern[h[x_, y_]] :> 2 x t] /. t -> x + y ]};
```

[image]